# Desplegar select modo edit en handsontable de Angular

Tags: angularjs

tengo una handsontable con varias filas, en cada una de ellas, hay celdas editables, en cada una de estas celdas, hay un select.

¿Se podría hacer que el select se desplegase automáticamente al poner la celda en modo edición? Sin tener que pulsar primero para poner en edición, y pulsar otra vez para desplegar el select.

Esta es la definición de una columna de ejemplo:

```
            data: 'tracking',
            readOnly: true,
            editor: 'select',
            renderer: utilsHandson.renderValue,
            selectOptions: ['A', 'B'],
            className: 'editable'
```

Gracias!

Comment: Hola y bienvenido David, ¿podrías incluir en tu pregunta la parte del código que ya tienes echa? Así podremos adaptar mejor las posibles respuestas ya que en caso contrario hay múltiples respuestas. Un saludo!

Comment: Hola, he editado poniendo la definición de la columna, espero que sirva.

Comment: Debes agregar un ejemplo que nos ayude a reproducir lo que estás intentando. Con la definición de la tabla no es suficiente.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta, como digo, estoy intentando que, con un solo click, mi celda sea editable y, además, el select que aparece, se despliegue. Si te fijas en este enlace http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/ , para poner la celda editable, necesitas un doble click, y luego, otro click para desplegar el select. He conseguido activar el edit con un solo click, lo que no consigo es desplegar el select. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que necesitas utilizar un [TriggerHandler](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/). Un ejemplo de ello lo puedes encontrar en el Stack Overflow en ingles: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447374/how-to-trigger-ng-click-angularjs-programmatically

Comment: Hola! Gracias por la respuesta, pero sigue sin funcionar, por algún motivo no puedo disparar eventos click manualmente, ha de ser cosa de la handsontable :S.